# command not found: shopt during anaconda installation process

Tags: bash, terminal, installation, anaconda

I installed anaconda and  it gives me this output in the terminal 
[after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPMNT.png)

and when i'm trying the source ~/.bashrc command it gives me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m808z.png)

Comment: Paste text, don't link screenshots. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) -- images aren't searchable, they aren't copy-pasteable, not not everyone can see them, we can't tell the difference between characters that look alike, etc.

Comment: That said, `shopt` not being found means you're running your code with `sh` when it's written for `bash`. Those are two different shells, and are not interchangeable.

Comment: (though I'm not sure that's `sh` you're using, it's *certainly* not bash either; if you want to use bash-only code, you need to use bash as your shell).